# Error creating bean with name 'hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]:

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, spring-mvc, pom.xml

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Could not autowire field:
>   com.programcreek.helloworld.controller.CountryService
>   com.programcreek.helloworld.controller.CountryController.countryService;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'countryService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.programcreek.helloworld.controller.CountryDAO
>   com.programcreek.helloworld.controller.CountryService.countryDao;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'countryDAO': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   com.programcreek.helloworld.controller.CountryDAO.sessionFactory;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]:
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert
>   property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type
>   'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'annotatedClasses'; nested exception
>   is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class
>   [org.arpit.java2blog.model.Country]

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>test Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.24</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>test</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.programcreek.helloworld.controller" />
 <annotation-driven />
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix">
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views/</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="suffix">
            <beans:value>.jsp</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nstoreb2cbeta" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>org.arpit.java2blog.model.Country</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: What is the whole error?

Comment: added the whole error

Comment: `Cannot find class [org.arpit.java2blog.model.Country` Is this in your project structure, in a src/main/java directory?

Comment: changed the class in dispatcher-servlet. now the error gone. but not displaying the pages. getting 404. this is the warning i am getting.WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/test/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: New error, new question, please, but it is possibly related to the fact that you have not wired /api/ in your web.xml

Comment: thanks man. just curious how did you find out the issue?

Comment: Go all the way to the end of the nested exceptions list. Spring exceptions are spectacular because they cascade, so going to the start of the cascade is typically the problem unless it is a cyclic exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve Spring dependency issues, navigate to the root Nested Exception. Typically, auto-wiring will be a slew of nested exceptions that dependencies cannot be autowired, so the specific bean failure will be hidden at the bottom of the original exception log. In this case...

> Cannot find class [org.arpit.java2blog.model.Country]

As this is not listed as a possible `orp.arpit.java2blog` dependency in the pom.xml, it must reside within the `src/main/java` directory or any other defined source directories within the Maven project itself. Either the class is incorrectly typed in the servlet, or the file is incorrectly placed in the project.